# Force stop of optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

The following function are just to express the problem not the real ones.
I have an objective function and I set a termination threshold:

```
def objective(x,data1,data2):
    s=data1-x*data2
    if s<=threshold:
       sys.exit()
    else:
       return s
```

I optimise with another function:

```
def optimize(data1,data2):
x0=numpy.zeros(2)
result=scipy.optimize.minimize(objective,x0,
                  args=(data1, data2),
                  method='Nelder-Mead', options={'xtol': 1e-6, 'disp': True})
return result
```

The problem is that due to the forced termination of the objective function, the optimisation does not return me the correct result i.e.the values **result.x** when the script terminates.

Unfortunately I cannot provide the original functions but if someone who has faced something similar maybe can help me.

Comment: Why use sys.exit()? Can't you just return None or something?

Comment: I'm asking the question because I don't get why you are using `sys.exit()`. Providing an example wouldn't help.

Comment: To terminate my procedure under a condition but i will give a try to your advice.

Comment: You shouldn't use `sys.exit()` for that, that function ends your python program. Instead, return a value that `scipy.optimize.minimize` will consider irrelevant and throw away. Perhaps `None` or something really high, for example.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood that you also want to end your program with the then-best value. `minimize` does not support that as far as I can tell,  [minimize-scalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#bounded-minimization-method-bounded) will perhaps suit you better.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use that optimisation.